# C console program: disable console window also disables printf (stdout)

Tags: c, printf, dev-c++

I need to use printf to send stdout to another program, which will call this C-made program. It printfs the foreground window title.

I do not want the console window to appear, as this will change the focused window. However, when I set the linker option to hide the console window (using DevCpp 5.10), printf sends nothing to stdout (verified calling the program from the MS-DOS command line).

How can I change the project settings (as this seems to be related to DevCpp rather than C) to hide the window and keep stdout working?

Comment: If the console window doesn't appear, how do you know that `printf()` doesn't send anything to `stdout`?

Comment: This isn't really a C question, but rather a DevC++ / Windows question.  C just knows about `stdout`, not about what it's connected to, or how that connection is set up.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Many times stdout can be used to send data to another program, usually the parent process.

Comment: I use the DOS window to call my program. printf only sends output when I set the console window to appear.

Comment: Maybe the operating system is smart enough not to write to stdout when it knows that it can't be seen (like when the console window isn't shown). Why should it write to the console when there is no console for the output to be written to?

Comment: @KenWhite It isn't hard to redirect stdout to somewhere other than the console.

Comment: Yes, I am perfectly aware of I/O redirection and pipes. My question still stands: how do you know that printf() sends nothing to stdout? In other words, please describe what steps you are taking to run your program to verify its behavior.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Yes, I'm aware of how redirection works. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite My point is that just because the console isn't visible doesn't mean that there isn't some other process connected to stdout to recieve the output. Of course, the OS might be smart enough to detect whether stdout is redirected to any process. (Maybe this is what you meant by your earlier comment and I'm just being pedantic about the word "console".)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: This appears to be a windowed application that is attempting to use console output without creating a console. (See the references to foreground window and changing focus.) The OS may not be producing the console output because it wouldn't appear anywhere, because the UI is supposed to be a window and turning off the console window in DevC++ removes the call to AllocConsole that would enable it.

Comment: So, the only workaround is to let the console window visible and, from the caller program, ask the called c-process not to show any window?

Comment: I've found out that redirection to a file works, even if the program has no window. Does this help to see what is happening?

Comment: "I've found out that redirection to a file works" That means that `printf()` is in fact sending output to `stdout`. So what is the actual problem? What are you doing that doesn't work the way you want it to?

Comment: If calling the windowless program from MS-DOS command line shows no output, I thought it is not being sent, so any request from another program won't work. Or will it just because redirection to a file works?

Comment: I tested and stdout is accessible from other programs, regardless of my C program using or not a window. Only the MS-DOS console cannot view stdout when I suppress my C program window. I don't know why MS-DOS has this issue, and it made me lose time thinking there were a problem with Dev-Cpp.

Comment: perhaps just use: `program1 | program2` to pipe the stdout from `program` to stdin of `program2`